# How to separate Print report in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

In Sale Module, We Create Sale Order and Quotation Reports. Both Reports are displayed in print button. We need to separate that reports based on Quotation and Sale Order.

We Using same Model name for sale and Quotation but write different view file.

Answer (score 1):

- You try this code for create two different button with same code but change string and Id.

  `<report 
          id="report_sale_order"
          string="Quotation"
          model="sale.order" 
          report_type="qweb-pdf"
          file="sale.report_saleorder" 
          name="sale.report_saleorder" 
      />`

Answer (score 1):

In sale order and quotation reports, If you conform the quotation it will print the sale order report and does not print quotation report.So it's separated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply a domain over that menu, you should remove this menus and use/create buttons to print Quotation or Order, you can apply domain over a button.